# как соединить два файла?

Tags: c++

создал два файла
game.cpp
game.hpp,
создал класс в одном из файлов, но в другом пишет, что нужно создать класс,
пробовал подключить

## include "Game.hpp"

пишет что не удается открыть файл,
что делать? (visual studio 2017)
[image: код]

Comment: Пожалуйста не меняйте вопрос кардинально после того, как получили ответ. Если у вас новый вопрос - задайте его новым постом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для заголочных файлов проекта, которые в создали используйте:

```
#include "Game.hpp"
```

[Если подключаемый файл указан в <>, то поиск будет происходить в стандартных каталогах, предназначенных для хранения заголовочных файлов. В случае, если подключаемый файл заклю­чен в двойные кавычки, поиск будет происходить в текущем рабочем каталоге. Если файл не найден, то поиск продолжается в стандартных каталогах.](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/include)

Answer (score 3):

Если просто, то треугольные скобки: `<...>` - для "системных" инклудов.
Либо для библиотечных инклудов, пути к которым вы указали в настройках проекта.

Вместо них есть кавычки: `"..."`. Такие файлы компилятор ищет в той же папке, в которой находится текущий файл.
(Если в этой папке нужного файла нет, проверяются те же папки, что и для `<...>`.)